# angular значение в списке по дефолту

Tags: angular7

есть `select`:

```
        <select (ngModel)="this.Categories" (change)="onclick_select_update($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let cat of Categories;" [selected]="cat.id === 10" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.title}}</option>
        </select>
```

Почему не отображается категория с id == 10 в списке??? Вместо этого дефолтное значение пустое (см. картинки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен:
Привязка `(ngModel)="this.Categories"` лишняя.

Comment: @meine объясните, что я сделал не так?